# Add rounded corner mask to icon using $linkImg variable

Tags: css, icons, rounded-corners, mask

Not as savvy on this as I'd like to be, so forgive me if my question is not phrased correctly.

Need to apply four rounded corners to a 119 x 119 App Store icon png auto pulled via a custom WordPress plugin using the variable $linkImg.

```
    $strHtml = "
<div style='border: solid 1px #00b7f3; background-color: #f8f8f8; width: 656px; height: 186px; padding: 0px; float: left; margin-top: 4px;'>
 <div style='float: left; width: 175px; margin: 0px; text-align: center; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 15px;'>
  <img src='$linkImg' width='119' height='119' style='margin: 0px; padding: 15px;'/>
 </div>
</div>
";
```

Any ideas? (Btw, first post)

**Edit 2 - This seems to do nothing, am I missing something obvious?**

```
    $strHtml = "
<div style='border: solid 1px #00b7f3; background-color: #f8f8f8; width: 656px; height: 186px; padding: 0px; float: left; margin-top: 4px; border-top-left-radius: 50px 50px;'>
 <div style='float: left; width: 175px; margin: 0px;  text-align: center; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 15px;'>
  <img src='$linkImg' width='119' height='119' style='margin: 0px; padding: 15px;'/>
 </div>
</div>
";
```

Comment: There's no function `$linkImg`, in your case it's a *variable*. Also, PHP doesn't have much to do with this, unless you want to talk about on-the-fly image manipulation. Do you know how to do it without PHP?

Comment: Depending on your usage, and browser support required you might be able to implement this with css rounded corners.

Comment: Hello deceze, thanks for the reply. Ahh, I see. As for knowing how to it without PHP, unfortunately not. Can you possibly help on that front?

Comment: Jacob, sounds interesting, thanks. Can you possibly provide a link with further information? The plugin I modified doesn't seem to come with .css file, style is seemingly controlled by the php document.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of css not php.

Use inline css if you cannot link an external css file.

Try http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border for Css3 rounded corners.

And http://www.devwebpro.com/25-rounded-corners-techniques-with-css/ for other hacks.

************edit*********** 
I am using operamini so I can't read your code. Also I can't post comments due to a wierd js issue.

The problem with css3 is it is not supported by all browsers and each browser currently does not use the standard. You need to find the -moz- specific and -webkit- specific versions. It isn't guaranteed to work unless the browser uses an engine which supports it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, frostymarvelous. Would you know how to implement the mask via .css?

Comment: Okay, tried the Css3 rounded corners method, see Edit 2 (above). Did I implement the .css right? - Thanks!